# Q: Related Rates

Tags: calculus, derivatives

A light is at the top of a $14$ ft. pole. A boy $5$ ft. tall is walking away from the pole at $3$ ft./sec. At what rate is the length of the boy's shadow increasing when he is $18$ ft. from the pole?

So I have the following:

1. $x$ stands for the distance between the pole and the boy, $y$ stands for the length of the shadow casted, and $z$ stands for the length of the light ray.
2. $z^2$ = $(x + y)^2$ + $14^2$ implies that $z \cdot \frac{dz}{dt} = (x + y) \cdot \frac{dx}{dt} + \frac{dy}{dt}$
3. Finding y by use of similar triangles: $\frac{14}{5} = \frac{(18 + y)}{y}$ implies $y = 10$
4. Finding $z$ by the pythagorean theorem: $z = \sqrt{14^2 + 28^2}$ implies $z = 14\sqrt{5}$
5. Finding $dz/dt$: we have $z^2 = 14^2 + (x + 10)^2$ which implies $dz/dt = 6/\sqrt{5}$
6. Lastly, plugging everything back into equation obtained from 2. yields the following: $dy/dt = -3/2$

This last value is negative which is impossible, so I'm not sure where I made my mistake.

Comment: In 4, $z = \sqrt{14^2 + 28^2}$. What is that $28$?

Comment: 28 is the sum of x and y. x = 14 and y was found to be 10.

Comment: Meant to say dy/dt not dz/dt

Answer (score 1):

Note that $$\frac{14}{5}=\frac{x+y}{y}.$$ Therefore, $$y=\frac{5}{9}x.$$ Consequently, $$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{5}{9}\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{15}{9} ft/sec.$$

Answer (score 0):

Using similar triangle,

$$\frac{y}{5} = \frac{x+y}{14}$$

This should be enough to relate $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with step 5, which differentiates the equation

$$z^2 = 14^2 + (x + 10)^2$$

However, the equation assumed that $\frac{dy}{dx}=0$ and $y$ is a constant $10$, which is wrong.

The following steps is what I guess OP was doing:

$$\begin{align*}
2z \frac{dz}{dt} &= 2(x+10)\frac{dx}{dt}\\
14\sqrt 5 \frac{dz}{dt} &= (18+10)\cdot 3\\
\frac{dz}{dt} &= \frac{6}{\sqrt 5}
\end{align*}$$